# Pattern matching on enum

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I'm trying to make utility which can pattern-match on enums (I hate switch statements).
This is what I currently have but this is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
type ObjWithStringValues = Record<string, number> | Record<string, string>
type Values<T extends {}> = T[keyof T]

export const matchEnum =
  <Res, Enum extends ObjWithStringValues>
  (e: Values<Enum>, matcher: {[Value in Values<Enum>]: Res}) =>
    matcher[e]

enum SomeEnum {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B'
}

const a: SomeEnum = SomeEnum.A

// expecting type of b to be 'foo' | 'bar' but instead I'm getting unknown
const b = matchEnum(a, {
    [SomeEnum.A]: 'foo',
    [SomeEnum.B]: 'bar'
})
```

Comment: There is no pattern matching in JS/TS, so you will wind up with something that is equivalent with a switch statement wrapped in a function.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/oN951N) work for you?  If not, can you elaborate?  If so, I'll write it up.

Comment: @jcalz, I like your solution. One problem I see is that enum cases can be unhandled without error, e.g we can leave
`matchEnum(a, {[SomeEnum.A]: 'foo'})` and there is no error about missing `SomeEnum.B` case

Comment: @scriptum some utility function that encapsulates matching behavior is exactly what I need

Comment: There’s no error because the compiler knows that `a` is `SomeEnum.A`.  If you miss a case that the compiler thinks can actually happen, it should warn.  Can you demonstrate a situation where it doesn’t?

Comment: @dps Please [review this](https://tsplay.dev/nWP8zW) and let me know if you have any more concerns before I write this up as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz I see, it's working properly, please create an answer. Thank you!